# Is there a way to move attachments from Google Inbox to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, inbox-by-gmail

In the new **Google Inbox** is there a way to **Save to Drive** (Google Drive) like there is in the original GMAIL?

In GMAIL, there's this:

[image]

In INBOX, I'm not seeing it:

[image]

Anyone know if this feature just isn't in Inbox yet or where it was moved to? Searching has just found a lot of people searching for Inbox invites, or instructions for gmail.

Comment: You are not seeing it because its already in your Google Drive.

Comment: What are you talking about @Ramhound - its not in my Google Drive already?

Comment: Are you sure?  I am pretty sure I read some place that it was automatic.

Comment: @Ramhound no, I'm not sure but I'm looking in Google Drive right now and don't see anything that indicates otherwise to me. Certainly possible there's some new section though I don't know about

Comment: I guess this is why it's in preview. Certainly you can save it to your local "Google Drive" folder (assuming you have the GDrive app installed), but apparently you can't (yet) save directly to Google Drive. The help documentation only mentions attachments as far as how to add them while composing. It makes no mention of managing attachments received.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019

Answer (score 9):

A quick workaround I found was to open the attachment, choose *Print* and then from the print menu, click *Change Destination* and select *Save to Google Drive*.

It will list the account it will be saved to, and this can be changed based on which Google account you are currently logged in on.

One small inconvenience with this method is that the saved file doesn't maintain it's original name, but is renamed to the long random string of the attachment URL. You can simply find it under Drive and then rename it to whatever you would like.

Comment: Decent work around, but keep in mind, this "Prints" a PDF file, so if you do it for docs, spreadsheets, etc, and what not, you won't be able to edit them.

Answer (score 4):

[Based on the product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/9M3b9u6-KrA) and my own experience, the feature doesn't seem to be there yet.

There are some workarounds for certain files that open in particular viewers (see [Ryan's answer on Android](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69950/83731)) but the old Gmail integration hasn't been added to Inbox *yet*.

Answer (score 2):

Oh just found it, on Android App at least so unfortunately can't post screenshot. Still not seeing it on Desktop App though.

On Phone when you click the file you get option to open with "Google Drive" or whatever other applicable programs you have (for me Drive PDF Viewer or Quickoffice). After choosing Drive PDF Viewer there's an option to save it to Drive.

Not seeing the same function on the Web App yet. Maybe if I download and install Google Drive's stand-alone application it would be there.

Comment: Note that this isn't quite the same as the Gmail feature. The Gmail command saves the attachment directly to Drive without the file ever residing on your computer; it goes directly from one Google server to another. When you choose "save to Drive" in the PDF viewer, the file has already been downloaded to your phone, and the command uploads that file to Drive. Not recommended for large files or where data usage is limited.

Comment: http://www.greenbot.com/article/2825064/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-your-android-phone.html ...